# set an option selected by value

Tags: jquery

In HTML i have dropdown like:

```
<select style="width:40%;" name="article[subsection_id]" id="article_subsection_id" class="article_subsection_cls"><option value=""></option>
    </select>
```

After appending options to the dropdown through jquery and using the below code:

```
var dropdown = $('select.article_subsection_cls').filter(function(){ 
    return !this.disabled; 
})[0];
console.log(dropdown);
```

I am getting this in browser console:

```
<select style="width:40%;" name="article[subsection_id]" id="article_subsection_id" class="article_subsection_cls">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">SubSectionxx</option>
    <option value="2">test</option>
    <option value="3">ProfileSubSectionxx</option>
</select>
```

Now i want to set selected for an option where `value="3"`.

Help me out.

Comment: try this `$('#article_subsection_id option[value=3]').prop('selected','selected')`

Comment: `$(dropdown).find('#article_subsection_id option[value=3]').prop('selected','selected')` try this way

Comment: are you appending the dropdown to body? the first one should work

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dqfa8tqo/) check demo

Comment: no, through jquery i am appending only options to the select element.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dqfa8tqo/1/)

Comment: Can you post the code where you append the `option`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$('select.article_subsection_cls').filter(function() {
  return !this.disabled;
}).val("3").change();
```